# Why doesn't the 'HAVING' function work in RdfLib SPARQL queries?

Tags: sparql, having, rdflib

I'm trying to use the HAVING funtion in a SPARQL query. While the query works fine in Protege, it does not return any result when I use it in a query in the rdflib package(it does not raise an error either). Is it not supported in this package? or is there any other problem?

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT ?sub ?p (COUNT(?obj) AS ?numobj)

WHERE {

?sub      ?p    ?obj

}
GROUP BY ?sub ?p
HAVING (?numobj >= 2)
```

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is return all subjects that have a relationship with 2 or more objects (so, excluding subjects that only have relationship with only one object).

Comment: you can try `HAVING (COUNT(?obj) >= 2)` - and yes, this should not be possible, but who knows ...

Comment: also, does any other query return a result? Just asking because it wouldn't be the first time the darta wasn't loaded into the graph before querying

Comment: HAVING (COUNT(?obj) >= 2) Actually worked!! Thank you so much. I wish this was mentioned in the documentation. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure if they know that your query is a valid SPARQL query. You could open an issue on their Github project and ask for either adding to documentation of just implementing it

Comment: Could the solving comments here please be posted as an answer so that the naswer can be indicated and thus the question resolved?